# Issue reading excel with interop

Tags: c#, excel, interop

I am trying to read a specific excel file in this code:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
namespace ConsoleApp9
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ExcelReader excelReader = new ExcelReader();
            List<(string, string, string, string, string, string)> data = excelReader.ReadExcel("C:\\Users\\aquinn\\Desktop\\Read rows test.xlsx", "Sheet1");

            foreach ((string columnA, string columnB, string columnC, string columnD, string columnE, string columnF) in data)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"A: {columnA}, B: {columnB}, C: {columnC}, D: {columnD}, E: {columnE}, F: {columnF}");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But it says that it cannot find the file? Ive looked at the PIA, added interop as a reference, installed the package and it still does not work, can anyone help please?

I tried to read this file and expected the writeline to output each of the rows, but the error regards PIA or some sort of add on to read the path way

```
    public class ExcelReader
    {
        public List<string[]> ReadRowsFromExcel(string filePath, string sheetName)
        {
            List<string[]> rows = new List<string[]>();

            using (var package = new ExcelPackage(new FileInfo(filePath)))
            {
                ExcelWorksheet worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets[sheetName];
                if (worksheet != null)
                {
                    int rowCount = worksheet.Dimension.Rows;
                    int columnCount = worksheet.Dimension.Columns;

                    for (int row = 1; row <= rowCount; row++)
                    {
                        string[] rowData = new string[columnCount];
                        for (int column = 1; column <= columnCount; column++)
                        {
                            var cellValue = worksheet.Cells[row, column].Value;
                            rowData[column - 1] = cellValue?.ToString() ?? string.Empty;
                        }

                        rows.Add(rowData);
                    }
                }
            }

            return rows;
        }
    }
```

Comment: `ExcelReader` what is this? Is this a class that you have defined yourself, or do you prefer to give me a reference page to check out? ?

Comment: @OscarSun Apologies, I have added this code also

Comment: So you using **EPPlus** (`ExcelPackage`) , right ? Then how is `ReadExcel` method you implemeted?  Then why do you still `using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;` isn't it should be `using OfficeOpenXml;`, right? Using **Interop** or **EPPlus** , which one do you actually want to use to implement it?

Comment: If im completely honest im not 100% sure im just trying to read the excel file in the above code and that is my best attempt... I shall try using officeopenxml and see if it works thank you @OscarSun

Comment: You mean you even don't know what is different between the interop and EPPlus? At least first you have to choose one of them to implement what you need. If you just run code in an Excel-installed environment, then using Interop will be recommended, otherwise EPPlus instead.